# What kind of things should go into a Ruby gem as opposed to a Rails plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, rubygems

I have a set of functionality that I am considering packaging so as to use them in multiple projects, but I can't decide whether to choose a gem or a plugin. What is the difference? Which one should I choose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Ruby on Rails, what's the difference between installing something as a gem or as a plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629919/in-ruby-on-rails-whats-the-difference-between-installing-something-as-a-gem-or)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gem is currently acknowledged as the 'best practice' for Rails. (You can also package as a gem and include an `install.rb` so that your project can be optionally be installed as a plugin - see this [Rails dispatch article](http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/how-rails-3-enables-more-choices-part-1)).

Basically the only reason to go with a plugin is if your users will want to be able to modify the code more often than not, as it stores a copy in `vendor/plugins`. However, with the advent of `bundler` it's pretty simple to store your gems per repository as well and modify them.

If you go with gems, you get the advantages of dependencies, versions, and the functionality that rubygems.org offers for searching, alerts and so on.

Definitely make it a gem!