# what's the difference between gem and plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails and I'm confused about concept of gems & plugins. Can anyone explain them for me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Ruby on Rails, what's the difference between installing something as a gem or as a plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629919/in-ruby-on-rails-whats-the-difference-between-installing-something-as-a-gem-or)

Answer (score 8):

Plugins are just libraries loaded from a specific directory, gems are loaded via [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) or [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/) directly.

Where this really makes a differences is maintenance and management. What happens when you want the latest and greatest authlogic plugin, well you need to update the files in your directory.  That doesn't sound so bad when it's one plugin, but what about something that constantly updates? There was/is an existing system for code packaging and distribution (RubyGems), which lends itself to managing such things.

Consider the authlogic example again, what happens if the new version requires some other dependency now? With RubyGems the gem file explicitly defines that relationship, the plugin system does not and such a definition would've been redundant.

With the advent of [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) in rails 3.x it's become very easy to manage and distribute the gems that your project uses.

TL;DR: Plugins are basically gems without the packaging information.

Answer (score 1):

Plugins are being used less and less so stick with gems. Gems and plugins can do exactly the same thing so that is why they are confusing. However the differences are how they are organized and most importantly how gems are managed such as `bundler` or `config.gem`. It is much easier to manage gems and their versions. Plugins must be installed in the `vendor` folder where as `gems` can also be installed in that folder if they need to be customized or they can be installed in a gem directory as long as rails understands where that directory is located. When rails started most people used plugins to added functionality but developers quickly realized that gems offered a better way to package and update libraries so most plugins have migrated to gems and fewer plugins are being built.

Answer (score -1):

**Gem and Plugin**

gem is stored in lib files

A Gem is a packaged Ruby application using the packaging system defined by RubyGems.

plugins are stored in vendors/plugins

A Rails plugin is a packaged Ruby application that extends the core Rails framework.