# Confused about gems/plugins and how I would add functionality to a Rails project

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

So I am looking to make some changes to a rails project (https://github.com/fatfreecrm/fat_free_crm).

So far the added functionality has come from plugins written for it. But it seems plugins are being depreciated for gems. So should the plugins be re written as gems. All I want is to add specific functionality for that app (vendored plugin like).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would only take a little bit of rework to change from plugins to Gems.

Is there something specific you are trying to change?

Answer (score 0):

Plugins and Gems fulfill the same functionality. Gems are just better at handling managing dependencies. They're also easier to share and deploy. You can look at this question for more  [information on gems/plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252319/whats-the-difference-between-gem-and-plugin)

If what you're looking for is resources on how to build a gem, you can have a look at [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler)