# Creating own Rails generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, code-generation, generator

I would like to know how to create a rails generator, which is available to all projects, but I only found the rails generate generator command for a single project.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby on Rails Guides chapter on [Creating and Customizing Rails Generators & Templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) has the details about how to creating your own generator.

It only deals with how to implement a generator in a specific project. To make it available across projects, you need to package the code as a plugin or a gem.

A plugin would be installed as a folder within each app that requires it, where as a gem will be installed directly via `bundler` or `rubygems`. See more about the difference between a plugin and a gem at [What's the difference between gem and plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252319/whats-the-difference-between-gem-and-plugin)

Check out [How to Make your own gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/) on the RubyGems site.

There are a lot more useful resources out there for creating a gem available by googling.